# Can I rescue any data if one of two drives in Striped Linux LVM failed?

Tags: raid, lvm, data-recovery

I have a Scientific Linus 6.7 box that serves some applications on our network. The person who set it up is no longer around. This morning machine stopped booting. There are two HDD's and they both show up in BIOS. If I put another HDD in, it boots fine.

I ran Ubuntu from another drive and Gparted shows the original drives are LVM2. I installed LVM and can see that they were configured to be used as one logical drive of combined capacity.

My hunch is that one of the drives failed. Can I rescue any data?

Comment: Maybe with photorec... It would be much faster to restore from your backup.

Answer (score 1):

Losing half of a striped set means that alternating chunks of data (based on stripe size, 4kB to 512kB) will be on the missing drive. Unless your critical files are very small in nature they are likely to be incomplete. Specialized facilities might be able to resurrect the bad drive and reconstitute the LVM set long enough for an export, otherwise it'll be an effort to recover whatever files are entirely stored on the remaining drive.

Whether that kind of recovery is feasible for you depends on your resources and the criticality of the data.

That all said, it is a very bad idea to store the Source Of Truth for anything solely on a single HD and even less so on a striped RAID set.  Hopefully anything critical was backed up; that is the best recovery option.